# Retrieve an amount value from firebase make a subtraction and update amount using swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using  swift 3 and firebase to build an app, I would like to retrieve an amount from the database make a subtraction and then update the amount on firebase again. I have a function as you'll see below with my firebase data structure.

Function:

```
func updateBal(cred: String){
    //creating artist with the new given values

    if ( cred != "" ) {
        let credit = ["credits": cred]
        let newCredit = credit as! Int
        let bal = newCredit - 1

        //let newBalanceString: [AnyHashable: Any] = [:]
        //let newBalanceString: [AnyHashable: Any] = [AnyHashable(bal): "/(bal)"]

        let newBalanceString = String(format:"%.2f", bal)
        ref.child("users").child(self.user.uid).child("creditdetails").childByAutoId().updateChildValues(newBalanceString)

        //displaying message
        //LabelMessage.text = "Balance Updated!"
    }
}
```

Data Structure

[image: Data Structure]

When I uncomment  the line with `[AnyHashable: Any]`, the app crashes on this line:

```
let newCredit = credit as! Int
```

But when I comment out the line with `[AnyHashable: Any]`, I get an error on the line:

```
ref.child("users").child(self.user.uid).child("creditdetails").childByAutoId().updateChildValues(newBalanceString)
```

Error says:

> Cannot convert value of type String to expected argument type [AnyHashable: Any]

Could you please point me in the right direction as to how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The line `let newCredit = credit as! Int` should always get you an error. You can't convert a Dictionary type to an Int type. To retrieve the credits as an Int you can do it like that :

```
if let newCredit = Int(cred) {
    let bal = newCredit - 1
}
```

As your `cred` value is retrieved as an Int, there's no need to specify a type `%.2f`
Also, you can directly create your Dictionary like in the following (with "credits" string as the key, as it's always this value) :

```
if let newCredit = Int(cred) {
    let bal = newCredit - 1

    let newBalanceString = ["credits" : bal]
    ref.child("users").child(self.user.uid).child("creditdetails").childByAutoId().updateChildValues(newBalanceString)
}
```

Comment: Hi Damien i did like your suggestion but still does not deduct on firebase. I cant seem to get it to work. Is there another work around to make it work

Comment: If you don't have errors anymore that's a start. Now you don't see any update on Firebase ? Look at your firebase rules (autorisations), check what exactly you are sending from your app.